# trouble using streaming xml loader in Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I'm new to Pig and was having trouble just trying to load an xml file.  It seems to have trouble importing or resolving the Streaming Xml Loader.  What do I need to configure or import the parser correctly?

```
       data = LOAD './data/small.xml'
       USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.StreamingXMLLoader(
          'Document',
          'test'
       ) AS (
           test:    {(attr:map[], content:chararray)}
       );
```

And this is the error

```
org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.StreamingXMLLoader using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse:
```

UPDATE: I registered piggybank and now it can resolve XMLLoader, but it cannot find StreamingXMLLoader

```
ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.StreamingXMLLoader using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like streaming xml loader is only avaialble on Mortar's version of Pig.

Here's the reply from mortar:

> StreamingXMLLoader is only available in Mortar's version of Pig at the
>   moment, though we do hope to contribute it back in the future. For
>   using Pig outside of Mortar, XmlLoader is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `StreamingXMLLoader` UDF from piggybank, yes, you'll need to import at the start of the script.

e.g.

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar;
```

Comment: just added the register statement and it still seems to be giving me an error ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.StreamingXMLLoader using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Comment: However it looks like it can load XMLLoader just fine, it just cannot find StreamingXMLLoader

Comment: Is it a Mortar only plugin? http://blog.mortardata.com/post/61678005593/xml-pig-loader

Answer (score 0):

Even I had similar issues. I verified first the presence of class StreamingXMLLoader by decompiler tool jd-gui. You can find the same in screenshot provided.

Thereafter I followed the example  :
http://www.sppavankumar.com/xmlloader-for-pig-big-data/

It worked for me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to pig lib and check for Apache-Pig-XMLLoader-master
if not download and put in your pig lib location location

mine is:

/usr/local/hadoop/pig/lib/Apache-Pig-XMLLoader-master